# Understanding Swift argument notation in functions like tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I came accros Swift recently but there is something I don't understand. I wanna implement a tableView with cells. That I understand but the notation is a bit confusing for me.

I have this function from the UITableViewDataSource

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
```

Can you tell me what is numberOfRowsInSection ?? Is it a function with his parameter section ? I see the name of the function tableView returning an Int, the parameters tableView and section with their own type. But I really don't get it for numberOfRowsInSection.

And when this function is called ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are **internal** and **external** argument labels. You can use two different kinds of argument labels. Internal are used inside the function itself and external onces are used when you call the function.

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
              /\                           /\              /\
              ||                           ||              ||
           internal                     external        internal
```

Let's take an example function:

```
func test(str:String, thisIsATest str1:String){
    println(str1)//works
    println(thisIsATest)//error
}
```

Like you see, I print the `str1` value. But you will see, that it will work with the internal argument only.

But if you now call the function from outside like that:

```
test("hi", str1:"hi2")
```

It throws an error. Because you use the `internal` argument label. 
But if you now use the external argument label `thisIsATest`, it works:

```
test("hi", thisIsATest:"hi2")
```

Also you don't have to set external labels at all, but if you set external labels, you also have to set an internal label for it. But you have to set internal labels in some cases like in `init()` methods.

Even if it is easy to remind, I made myself a pony for that: I compare a function with a company: If you work in the company, and you want to call somebody who also works in the company, you will use the **internal** phone number. But if you want to use the company-service as a customer(user of a function),  you call from the **external** number.

Comment: Thanks Christian, it's very clear. It's basically a naming convention for Apple and for the developers to see what does the function do at the end ?  Do we know when the function is called ? or is it hidden by Apple ?

Comment: What do you mean with "do we know when the function is called"?. Well that has nothing to do with how the method is named.