# What is the (named) keyword in Xcode ?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimage

In Xcode, when i declare an object from uiimage class there is an init method which is declared as init?(named name: String), so i am wondering what is the **named** keyword ?

Comment: It's called internal and external keywords/argument labels. Check my answer on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677431/understanding-swift-notation-in-function-tableview/28677697?noredirect=1#comment45651771_28677697

Answer (score 0):

In Swift when you declare a function like this...

```
func foo(bar barName: String)
```

Then autocomplete will show `bar` but the internal variable name is `barName`.

IIRC it is there for convenience only. It provides context outside the function and a sensible variable name inside the function.

Without this then the variable inside the function would be called `named` not `name`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation **named** is

> The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being
>   loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the
>   application’s main bundle.

For instance if you have resource **icon.png**. You can create UIImage like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named:"icon")
```

**name** keyword is used internally in this methods. For instance if you will need to subclass UIImage and override `init?(named name: String) -> UIImage`you will use **name** keyword inside of this method to refer to image name.

Answer (score 0):

`named` is the external parameter name that is used when you call the `init`.

`name` is the local/internal parameter name this is used by the `init`

ex:

```
class x {
var a:Int
init(named name:Int){
    a = name // you cant use named here
}
}
var instance = x(named: 4) // you cant use name here
```